# can't connect to https API using cURL?

Tags: windows-7, https, curl, api

I have API endpoint URL, certificate file ( *cert.p12* ) & password. Here is the steps I try to connect to this API.

*( IN Windows 7 )*

- First I type the URL in chrome browser and it didn't give me any
  result.
- Then I import the `cert.p12` file by double clicking on it then it
  ask me for the password.

  I successfully import the certificate by typing password and then it's start showing in certmgr.msc → Personal → Certificates.
- Now Chrome can access the URL without any issues.

But still curl in same windows PC can't access the API Endpoint.
It's giving error :/

I need to know how to import this certificate to curl in both Windows & Linux ?